# Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex error

Tags: visualforce, controller, selectlist, selectoption

I am getting the error stated in the question. I have used a `<selectOption>` list in my controller and in my VF page, I have used `<apex: selectOptions>`. What is the issue?

I have attached my controller code and VF code below.

/*Apex Code*/

```
public String vectorUnit {get; set;}
   public List<SelectOption> getVector(){
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
      List<Resource__c> vectorList = new List<Resource__c>();
      vectorList = [Select Id, Name, Status__c, Type__c, Is_Active__c FROM Resource__c WHERE Status__c = 'Available' 
      AND  Type__c = 'Vector' AND Is_Active__c = TRUE];
      options.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
      for (Resource__c res : vectorList)
      {
          options.add(new SelectOption(res.Name,res.Name));
      }
      return options;
    }
```

/*VF page*/

```
   <apex:outputlabel value="Assigned Enhance Device" for="vector" />
   <apex:selectList value="{!vectorUnit}" size="1" id="vector">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!vector}"/>
   </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: what's the type of your `vectorUnit` variable that's set in `apex:selectList` ?

Comment: It's a string. I have mentioned that in the code

Comment: Can you try with multiple =  false

Comment: do you have any variable defined in the name `vector` in your controller?

Comment: I don't see any issue with this code. can you add your complete apex class. I tried to reproduce same in my org but it is working fine.

Comment: highfive was right! I had another variable called vector and that was the issue. highfive please post it as an answer so that I can mark it and close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted code in the question seems to be ok but this error can be occurred if you have any variable with the same name i.e. `vector` in your controller (with `get;`).

In this case `SelectOptions` tag in the UI may refer to that variable which is not in the required type of `List<SelectOption>`

Answer (score 0):

replace :

```
<apex:outputlabel value="Assigned Enhance Device" for="vector" />
<apex:selectList value="{!vectorUnit}" size="1" id="vector">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!vector}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

with :

```
<apex:outputlabel value="Assigned Enhance Device" for="vector" />
<apex:selectList value="{!vectorUnit}" size="1" id="vector">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!getVector}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: The get keyword prefixed to the method is the getter method. It throws an error if I include it in the VF page too

Comment: in saleforce if method is start with get then in page we can access without appending get... this is wrong `<apex:selectOptions value="{!getVector}"/>`.. this is correct `<apex:selectOptions value="{!vector}"/>` check doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm

Comment: i have used this as following  : 

  public List< SelectOption> allpayment{
} and then i used allpayment to show in VF page , its working for me

Comment: @patelkiran, that's because you haven't appended the keyword 'get'. If you prefix get in your apex code, you shouldn't prefix it in your VF page.
Ex: getNames() will be {!Names} in your VF page

Comment: Oh ok got it thnx